# Going back with gesture not work when keyboard is on react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-gesture-handler

When keyboard is appear, navigation back using gesture not work in react navigation with CardStyleInterpolators.forModalPresentationIOS.
When I hide keyboard it works.

This happening in android and I can not confirm it for iOS.

Here is what's happening:

[image: RN]

```
 "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.0",
 "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.7.0",
```

Comment: Did you import `import { gestureHandlerRootHOC } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';` and wrap your app by `gestureHandlerRootHOC` like this `AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => gestureHandlerRootHOC(App));` ?

Comment: @ShahnawazHossan Yes, as You can see when keyboard hide, it works.